# Why can't I successfully debug the .net coredump generated under Linux with VS2022?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, visual-studio-2022, coredump

I run the dotnet 7 executable file on Linux (Centos 7), and then a core dump occurs. I transferred the coredump, executable file, and pdb file to Windows, and then debugged with VS2022.

The following appeared:

"Managed debugging is not available for this minidump"

"The debugee memory space does not have the expected debugging export table".

Why is this?

**Some of info:**

Linux operation system : Centos 7.6

Windows operation system : Win10

dotnet version: dotnet 7

**Some of linux Environment Variable:**

ulimit -c unlimited

export DOTNET_DbgEnableMiniDump=4

export DOTNET_DbgMiniDumpType=4

export DOTNET_CreateDumpDiagnostics=1

export DOTNET_EnableCrashReport=1

export DOTNET_CreateDumpVerboseDiagnostics=1